# Error while trying to run the application using npm start

Tags: reactjs, npm-start

## I get this error when I run npm start in my project root folder

```
> 'More\React\starters\my-app\node_modules\.bin\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080
throw err;
>   ^

Error: Cannot find module 'D:\react-scripts\bin\react-scripts.js'
at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: []
> }

Node.js v18.17.1
```

I am getting an error while trying to launch the application with npm, which is giving me a path to debug but, I am not able to understand the error.
Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

Comment: What does `npm start` do? You haven't shared your *package.json* so that's pretty meaningless information.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to clean the cache. Try running these two commands:
`npm cache clean --force`
`npm install`